# Is solvability of diophantine equations over a p-adic field decidable?

Tags: number-theory, logic, diophantine-equations

As far as I understand, the decidability of solvability of diophantine equations over the rationals is an open problem. What about the decidability of solvability over a given p-adic field?

Comment: Decidable. Please see the very good survey article by [Poonen.](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/aws2003.pdf)

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you for the answer and reference.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Decidable. Please see the very good survey article by [Poonen.](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/aws2003.pdf)